# How do I select an object from a collection where 1 of 2 columns equals a value?

Tags: laravel

I have the following which returns a collection of objects;

```
        $cwGames = Schedule::where('date', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(7))
        ->where('date', '>', Carbon::now()->addDays(1))->get();
```

Now I want to select from this collection only the object where $id is in col A or $id is in col B.

What's the best way to do this?  Thanks.

Thanks to ExoticChimp for direction on the answer below.  I added the use ($id) to get it to work.  See edit here...

```
        $cwGames = Schedule::where('date', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(7))
        ->where('date', '>', Carbon::now()->addDays(1))
        ->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
            // Replace col_A and col_B with your column names
            $query->where('home_team_id', $id)
                ->orWhere('away_team_id', $id);
        })->get();
```

Comment: you should give this further tags e.g. the laravel version, and eloquent etc to help people find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is slightly ambiguous what you mean by col A and col B. However, if what you want is to add in an additional where clause which is effectively if colA or colB = $id, then the following should work (from the Laravel docs)

```
$cwGames = Schedule::where('date', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(7))
    ->where('date', '>', Carbon::now()->addDays(1))
    ->where('name', '=', 'John')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        // Replace col_A and col_B with your column names
        $query->where('col_A', $id)
              ->orWhere('col_B', $id);
        })
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Collections has a lot of cool features that I think you should check on the official docs. In your case, the "filter" method is the best way to process the elements of your collection.

According to the official docs:

> The filter method filters the collection by a given callback, keeping only those items that pass a given truth test

In your case:

```
$cwGames->filter(function($value, $key) {
    // If your check returns true, the element will be kept in the collection
}
```

Check the docs [here (filter method explained)](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-filter)